# Combinar dos txt en uno y hacer diferentes copias de formato para cada linea

Tags: c++

Tengo un archivo txt el cual es un formato de carta el cual tiene unas etiquetas que se tienen que reemplazar con datos de otro archivo txt. Logre separar cada dato del archivo datos.txt ya que cada uno estaba delimitado por comas y asi guarde cada datos en un vector llamado palabras. Luego logre hacer una carta reemplazando cada etiqueta de formato.txt con su respectivo dato, la cosa es que solo logro hacer esto con la primera linea de datos del archivo datos.txt que representa a un empleado. No he sabido como lograr hacer mi archivo cartas.txt con cartas para todo empleado.
La funcion es esta:

```
void cartas(){
    string replaceNombre= "<Nombre>";
    string replaceApellido = "<Apellido>";
    string replaceCelular = "<celular>";
    ifstream formato("formato.txt");
    ifstream datos;
    ofstream cartas("cartas.txt",ios::out);
    string temp;
    vector<string> palabras;
    datos.open("datos.txt");

    if(datos.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo crear el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    string linea;
    while(getline(datos,linea))
    {
        stringstream stream(linea);
        string palabra;

        while(getline(stream,palabra,','))
        {
            cout<<palabra<<endl;
            palabras.push_back(palabra);
        }
    }

 while(formato >> temp)
    {
        if(temp == replaceApellido)
        {
           temp = palabras[0];
        }
        if(temp == replaceNombre)
        {
           temp = palabras[1];
        }
        if(temp == replaceCelular)
        {
           temp = palabras[2];
        }
        temp += " ";
        cartas << temp;
    }
    formato.close();
    cartas.close();
}
```

El archivo formato.txt se ve asi:

COMPAÑIA EL PARCIAL S.A
<Nombre> <Apellido>
Ciudad

La compañia se encuentra en proceso de actualizacion de datos, por este motivo solicitamos
informarnos si el celular <celular> corresponde a su numero de telefono vigente

Cordial saludo
La gerencia

Y el archivo datos.txt se ve asi:

ramirez,ernesto,9238

ricon,pepe,920

zapata,laura,3092

El primer dato es el apellido, el segundo el nombre y el ultimo el celular. Como dije, se logro hacer el archivo cartas.txt que es la combinacion del formato con los datos, con la informacion de ernesto que es la primera linea del archivo de datos, pero no he logrado hacer que este archivo cartas.txt genere las cartas para los demas empleados.

Alguien sabe como deberia hacerlo. Se que a lo mejor debe ser con un ciclo for pero no se como deberia hacerlo. Gracias

Comment: Hola! Las preguntas sin código no son muy bien recibidas. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues el fragmento de código con el que tienes problemas para que así nos sea más fácil ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: puedes compartir el resto de archivos?

Comment: @Srsole Cuales otros?

Answer (score 1):

El primer acercamiento sería meter el bucle que genera la carta dentro del anterior, que itera sobre los empleados:

```
while(getline(datos,linea))
{
    stringstream stream(linea);
    string palabra;

    while(getline(stream,palabra,','))
    {
        cout<<palabra<<endl;
        palabras.push_back(palabra);
    }

    while(formato >> temp)
    {
        if(temp == replaceApellido)
        {
           temp = palabras[0];
        }
        else if(temp == replaceNombre)
        {
           temp = palabras[1];
        }
        else if(temp == replaceCelular)
        {
           temp = palabras[2];
        }
        temp += " ";
        cartas << temp;
    }
}
```

Pero con esta solución, la carta no puede tener saltos de línea, ya que los mismos se pierden al separar la carta por palabras y luego ya no puedes saber qué separador había entre cada par de palabras:

- Uno o varios espacios
- Una o varias tabulaciones
- Uno o varios saltos de línea
- Una combinación lineal de los casos anteriores

Así que puede ser mejor idea leer del tirón la carta y almacenarla en un `string`, después basta con ir reemplazando las etiquetas con los valores de cada empleado.

Eso si, antes de reemplazar la etiqueta hay que copiar el contenido de la carta que se encuentre entre la última etiqueta reemplazada y la actual.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Empleado
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::string apellido;
    int celular;
};

std::string LeerCarta()
{
    std::ifstream fichero("formato.txt");
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << fichero.rdbuf();
    return sstr.str();
}

std::vector<Empleado> LeerEmpleados()
{
    std::vector<Empleado> to_return;
    
    std::ifstream fichero("datos.txt");
    while(true)
    {
        Empleado empleado;
        if (!std::getline(fichero, empleado.nombre, ',')) break;
        if (!std::getline(fichero, empleado.apellido, ',')) break;

        fichero >> empleado.celular;
        if (fichero.eof()) break;

        fichero.ignore(); // Descartamos el salto de línea
        
        to_return.push_back(empleado);
    }
    
    return to_return;
}

int main()
{
    std::string carta_original = LeerCarta();
    
    std::vector<Empleado> empleados = LeerEmpleados();
    
    std::ofstream out("cartas.txt");

    size_t previous = 0;
    for (auto empleado : empleados)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            size_t pos_nombre = carta_original.find("<Nombre>", previous);
            size_t pos_apellido = carta_original.find("<Apellido>", previous);
            size_t pos_celular = carta_original.find("<celular>", previous);
        
            if (pos_nombre < pos_apellido && pos_nombre < pos_celular)
            {
                out << carta_original.substr(previous, pos_nombre - previous)
                    << empleado.nombre;
                previous = pos_nombre + 8;
            }
            else if (pos_apellido < pos_celular)
            {
                out << carta_original.substr(previous, pos_apellido - previous)
                    << empleado.apellido;
                previous = pos_apellido + 10;
            }
            else if (pos_celular != std::string::npos)
            {
                cout << carta_original.substr(previous, pos_celular - previous)
                     << empleado.celular;
                previous = pos_celular + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                out << carta_original.substr(previous);
                previous = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Está claro que el código podría ser más óptimo, pero también sería más ilegible.

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [AQUI](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xt9rD6qZRrGYhQCE)